# Prototypal Callback

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is simple, but I cannot get it working, even I have read many similar topics for hours. I don't know what else to search.

I want to call a callback function, but one within the object, not just a function in the global (?) scope.

```
var something = function (x) {
    this.x = x;
};

something.prototype.alertx = function() {
    alert(this.x);
};

something.prototype.logx = function() {
    console.log(this.x);
};

something.prototype.multiplyxby2 = function(callback){
    this.x *= 2;
    callback.call(this); // this is where I am stuck!!
    // obviously this.callback(); doesn't work either.
};

var foo = new something(20);
foo.multiplyxby2('logx');
// or
foo.multiplyxby2('alertx');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are passing the function to be called as a string, so you need to get the function reference to be executed. Since the function is a member of the `this` object, you can use the bracket notation as given below to get the function reference and then invoke it

```js
var something = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
};

something.prototype.alertx = function() {
  snippet.log('alertx:' + this.x);
};

something.prototype.logx = function() {
  snippet.log('logx:' + this.x);
};

something.prototype.multiplyxby2 = function(callback) {
  this.x *= 2;
  this[callback]();
};

var foo = new something(20);
foo.multiplyxby2('alertx');
foo.multiplyxby2('logx');
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

another option is to pass the function reference directly as the callback like

```
something.prototype.multiplyxby2 = function (callback) {
    this.x *= 2;
    callback.call(this); // this is where I am stuck!!
    // obviously this.callback(); doesn't work either.
};

var foo = new something(20);
foo.multiplyxby2(foo.alertx);
foo.multiplyxby2(foo.logx);
```

1. List item

Comment: Thank you sir!! What is the difference between `this[callback].call(this);`and `this.[callback]()` in jfriend00's answer? Just passing the context to the callback?

Comment: @BenA. there is none.... I also have updated the answer.... since we are invoking the callback using the correct context there is no need to use `.call()`

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: Be aware that passing object members as string and using it in the bracket notation will break your code when using almost any minifier.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to pass a method name as a string, then you can use the `[methodname]` syntax to reference it like `this[methodname]();` and here it is in your code block:

```
var something = function (x) {
    this.x = x;
};

something.prototype.alertx = function() {
    alert(this.x);
};

something.prototype.logx = function() {
    console.log(this.x);
};

something.prototype.multiplyxby2 = function(method){
    this.x *= 2;
    // execute the passed in method
    this[method]();
};

var foo = new something(20);
foo.multiplyxby2('logx');
// or
foo.multiplyxby2('alertx');
```